# Swift network monitor switches .satisfied and .unsatisfied statuses

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to monitor the network access of an iOS app.

When I run the simulator for a first time with wifi turned ON I get the right message "We're connected!".

But when I switch OFF the wifi I get the same message "We're connected!".

If I switch it on again I get the "No connection." message.

If I continue to switch the network on and off I get the opposite status of the actual state of the wifi.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong? Here's the code:

```
import Foundation
import Network

final class NetworkMonitor: ObservableObject {
    
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "NetworkMonitor")
    let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
    
    init() {
        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
            if path.status == .satisfied {
                print("We're connected!")
            } else {
                print("No connection.")
            }
        }
        monitor.start(queue: queue)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Running this in a playground exhibits a strange behavior, but not entirely as you describe. Switching network on/off always results in two status updates, first with `.satisfied`, and then the actual, correct status. Are you sure you never get the second update with the correct status?

Comment: I've tried to wait for 5 minutes and there's no update yet.

Comment: Have you tried it on an actual device? I suspect it might be something in the simulator. There are no network settings in the simulator itself as far as I can see.

Comment: I haven't tried it on a device yet. I hope that's the reason for the issue.

Comment: I am here because it's happening to me as well ... it triggers `unsatisfied` when the network is connected and vise versa...

Answer (score 2):

@tromgy was right that the code in the question seems to work on actual device but I'll post my workaround here.

NOTE: The environment check for a simulator seems optional to me but let me know if you have a different opinion.

```
import Foundation
import Network

final class NetworkMonitor: ObservableObject {

    static let shared = NetworkMonitor()
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "NetworkMonitor")
    let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
    @Published public private(set) var isConnected: Bool = false
    private var hasStatus: Bool = false
    
    init() {
        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
            #if targetEnvironment(simulator)
                if (!self.hasStatus) {
                    self.isConnected = path.status == .satisfied
                    self.hasStatus = true
                } else {
                    self.isConnected = !self.isConnected
                }
            #else
                self.isConnected = path.status == .satisfied
            #endif
            print("isConnected: " + String(self.isConnected))
        }
        monitor.start(queue: queue)
    }

}
```